# PowerPivot Count Duplicates

Tags: dax, powerpivot

would appreciate any help with this...

I have a table of Invoice Data, Including Company Number and Date, I need to count the number of duplicates where a company has more than one invoice for the same day. ( I need to count in PowerPivot itself, as I will be performing more calculations based on the results, so wouldn't want to drag into a pivot table at this stage )

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind Regards
Gavin[image: DAX]

Answer (score 0):

Please find the DAX:

```
Count :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Table1 ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Company], Table1[Date] )
)
```

Thanks